# Bot does not respond to other users on Facebook Channel

Tags: facebook, botframework

I have a bot that was developed using the Microsoft Bot Framework and it has a Facebook channel. If I chat to it using the Facebook profile of the user who created it (the Facebook app that is linked to the bot), it responds. But if I try  another user, it does nothing.

What could be causing this?

Comment: How about posting some of your code? Imagine asking someone if the spelling/grammar is correct in your essay, without letting them look at the essay...

Comment: @Sylverac What code would you like me to post. Its a framework related issue.

Comment: You could post your implementation of the framework as that is what you are having a problem with.

Comment: It's a valid question - no code needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook Bots have to be reviewed by Facebook before they are available to anyone other than page admins and the app developers. You can find more details on their development pages

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review

Comment: Please link to the exact page

Comment: I've added the link, though to be fair there's a whole section dedicated to messenger on their developer docs. As urls can and often do change I thought it easier for people to find it themselves

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your Facebook app as Public, by default your Facebook app is in development and it is not available to the public.